# How to use abstract class and Interface in hiding base class properties?

Tags: c#

I have created a base class as "Common" there are many properties such as pageno,pagesize,search,etc which will use in all classes for entire project(must require).
There is other class as "Area" which extends "Common" class.
All properties are automatic get and set.

Here the problem is,
I have created web api.It returned object of Area class.
So here client received all properties of area and common.But I need specific properties to response.
Means I just need two properties of Area i.t AreaId,AreaName

This requirement for retuned data in different format like JSON and XML.I did with linq it gives specific properties Which I need exactly. But It is anonymous type data. Not strongly object.
following sample of my code

```
    public class Common
    {
    public int CaseNo { get; set; }
    public int? RET_ID { get; set; }
    public string MSGSTATUS { get; set; }
    public string MSG { get; set; }
    public int? LoginId { get; set; }
    }


   public class Area : Common
    {
    public int AreaId { get; set; }        
    public string AreaName { get; set; }
    public string PinCode{ get; set; }
    }
```

/*Web api code*/

```
         public IHttpActionResult GetAreaById(int AreaId, int LoginId)
         {
        try
        {
            AreaDAL objDal = new AreaDAL();
            Area objBo = new Area();
            objBo = objDal.EditArea(AreaId, LoginId);

            if (objBo != null)
            {
           /*Not working for xml returned data(work for json).anonymous type data*/
             return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new Area { AreaId = objBo.AreaId, AreaName = objBo.AreaName }));

            /*working for json and xml */
            /*But it retuned all properties of Area and common*/
             /*Needed as AreaId and AreaName*/
             return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, objBo));

           }
         }
```

Comment: So your question is how to provide the object to the xml-response without writing `new Area...` or what specifically are you asking? What exactly does "not working" mean?

Comment: You mention "anonymous data", do you mean something like `new { AreadId, AreaName }` ? If so, what was the problem with that solution?

Comment: Yes, And Also need recommendation of class structure.If I use new {AreaId,AreaName} which not retuned as xml in web api

Answer (score 0):

Introduce an intermediate class (AreaInfo) and pull AreaId and AreaName members up:

```
    public class AreaInfo : Common
    {
      public int AreaId { get; set; }        
      public string AreaName { get; set; }
    }
    public class Area : AreaInfo
    {
      public string PinCode{ get; set; }
    }
```

//...

```
      public IHttpActionResult GetAreaById(int AreaId, int LoginId)
      {
        try
        {
            AreaDAL objDal = new AreaDAL();
            Area objBo = new Area();
            objBo = objDal.EditArea(AreaId, LoginId);

            if (objBo != null)
            {
               return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new AreaInfo { AreaId = objBo.AreaId, AreaName = objBo.AreaName }));

               return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, objBo));    
           }
       }
```

edit: for hiding fields in the Common base class, you can:

1) Change their access modifier (e.g. to protected)

2) Mark them with attributes to be skipped on serialization like:

**[XmlIgnore]** for xml serialization

**[JsonIgnore]** for json serialization

3) Separate the class hierarchies (Common from AreaInfo<-Area) and use composition for when you need
extra fields in Common class.
e.g.

```
public class Common<T>
  where T: class
{
  //... common fields here
  public T Data {get;}
  public Common(T data) => Data = data;
}
...
var area = new Common(new Area(){...});
//area.LoginId;
//area.Data.AreaId;
```

Comment: Your answer is not as expected because when I retuned AreaInfo object then It also contains Common class Properties.I do not want display or assign Common class properties.

Comment: edited the answer with some options for hiding the base class members,